# Command button inside jQuery SimpleModal window does not invoke action

Tags: jquery-plugins, jsf-2

I have created a DIV section in my page in the following way:

```
<div id="modalAlert" style="display: none;">
 <h:panelGroup layout="block">
   <p>My Heading </p>
   </h:panelGroup>
   <h:panelGroup layout="block">
   </h:panelGroup><h:panelGroup layout="block">
   <h:commandButton id="btnSaveConfirmation" value="save" action="#{myBean.method}"> </h:commandButton>                    
  </h:panelGroup>                           
</div>
```

And I am using the following JS script to display a SimpleModal window using jQuery:

```
function showAlert() {
    fundpickerdialog = $('#modalAlert').modal({
        opacity : 100,
        overlayCss: {backgroundColor:"#fff"},
        modal : true,
        dataId : 'modalAlert',
        classname: 'ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-draggable ui-resizable',
        closeOnEscape : false, 
        width : 50,
        height : 50
    }); 
}

$(document).ready(function() {

        showAlert();
    }   

});
```

The modal window is appearing but on clicking the Save button it's not calling the backing bean method.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the form tags (h:commandButton must be located inside a form), wrap the content of the div with  tags

try something like this:

```
<div id="modalAlert" style="display: none;">
 <h:form>
  <h:panelGroup layout="block">
  <p>My Heading </p>
  </h:panelGroup>
  <h:panelGroup layout="block">
  </h:panelGroup><h:panelGroup layout="block">
  <h:commandButton id="btnSaveConfirmation" value="save" action="#{myBean.method}"></h:commandButton>                  
  </h:panelGroup> 
 </h:form>                          
</div>
```

Comment: It's inside a form only. I have just shown the DIV section which is the part of the form

Comment: since i cant see the entire page... I'll make another guess... maybe you got form inside form? anyway try to get rid of others form and try the code spinet that I posted

Answer (score 0):

Some JavaScript/jQuery modal dialog approaches will remove the element representing the modal dialog and all of its children from its current position in the HTML DOM tree and re-insert it as immediate child of the `<body>` in order to prevent potential positioning and layering issues across various browsers. Since you didn't put the `<form>` inside the element representing the modal dialog, it will end up being form-less.

You really need to put the `<h:form>` *inside* the element representing the modal dialog.

Further, I recommend to use a JSF component library instead of an arbitrary jQuery plugin. For example [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org) has a [`<p:dialog>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialog.jsf) component for exactly this purpose. It has already taken potential nasty JSF-related side effects into account for you without that you need to write any additional line of JS/jQuery code.

Comment: Hi, not that its matter but, primefaces does not use jQuery UI under the cover in its dialog , http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=18100 "they got their own native dialog" :)